# Cannot authorise facebook with gwibber

Tags: gwibber, facebook

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I am fairly newbie so answers in words of one sylabel pls. When trying to add facebook to gwibber I get the following message.Any ideas pls. twitter works fine.

```
Unable to load page

Problem occurred while loading the URL https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?scope=publish_stream%2Cread_stream%2Cstatus_update%2Coffline_access%2Cuser_photos%2Cfriends_photos&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup&client_id=71b85c6d8cb5bbb9f1a3f8bbdcdd4b05

Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()
```